# Licensing system with PHP backend?

Tags: c#, licensing

I am about to release my app and am now trying to figure out how to solve the licensing.

Basically, i want to be able to offer customers an option to either pay a fee each month or a one time fee.

I dont really care about spending tons of time trying to secure it so it cant be cracked, if someone wants to crack the app they will anyway.. so this is more for the honest people.

I was thinking of having a backend in PHP that stores the different licence types in a MySQL database. In theory that makes sense to me, but i have no idea how to execute it in actual c# code..

Does anyone know how i could implement a basic licensing system so that i do not spend days on it? :)

Any help and tips are greatly appreciated!

Edit - to clarify:

I have a c# app, but it to check against a php backend script which stores the customers.

Comment: Ha, I'm actually porting a simple licensing service from C# to PHP today.  I think this question is too broad for SO, though.  You're basically saying "write my code."  Just get started and ask a more specific question when you hit a problem that you can't solve on your own.

Comment: Just to clarify. You have your entire web app hosted on php and you want to execute the same code on a C# backend? Are we talking about converting your php to C#? Because (unless I am wrong) C# and php are two different web server solutions.

Comment: @harpo yea your probably right, i should just start to execute :)

Comment: I think this question would be more fit for a different SE site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, a basic implementation would be as follows:

(psudo code)

MySQL DB with 2 tables:

```
TABLE user
    id int primary key auto increment
    username varchar not null
    password varchar not null

TABLE subscription
   id int primary key auto increment
   type int not null
   expires date not null
```

PHP Callback url: https://www.example.com/authenticate.php
returns: JSON or XML
takes: post data: username:user password:pass

PHP code checks the passed in username and password for correctness, and if correct, checks to see if they have a valid subscription. Returns JSON or XML as a response:

{status:true}
or
{status:false}

You may wish to expand the response to include the subscription type and expiration date so that the application can cache the subscription if they are offline and unable to talk to your server.

Your c# application would need to use code similar to the following (adapt to xml if that is preferable to you)

```
string URL = 'https://www.example.com/authenticate.php";
string myParameters = "username=user&password=pass";
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        // Now parse with JSON.Net
}
```

Obviously the above is not a fully functional piece of code, and I apologize for any syntax errors. You would use that code in an initialization step, and close the application with an error if they do not have a valid subscription (or use whatever behavior you wish).

Comment: The importance under a licensing service is to hide the method. A single True/False response from "a server" would be EASILY faked by hosts definitions. You have to mix that functions with a "fingerprintint function" that ensures that your program and only your program is performing the check. Other way is to use a non root ssh tunnel to verify data, cuz you cannot easily spy it's content, and you have to move to a debugger to hack it.

Comment: This answer was intended as a basic "here is how I would get started with the most simple approach possible" and doesn't go into any of the details or intricacies of securing a licensing system.

There are many commercial products with licensing systems that are easily faked or cracked which I am sure care far more about security, and the question specifically states that security isn't a concern.